# Gridview row color basing on the textbox value outside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change the background color of the Gridview row. The situation is I want to change the background color of that particular row whose BoundField Id is equal to the value displayed in the textbox outside the Gridview. I am able to achieve using RowDataBound and also in `!IsPostBack` and in page load too, but the problem is the color just flash off (quickly disappear in a fraction of millisecond) and does not stay (unable to hold). I have seen other similar example which is available but it doesn't meet my situation, so please don't mark as duplicate.

Below is my Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvCustomers_RowDataBound">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataTextField="AssetsName" HeaderText="Product" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataField="InventorySubName" HeaderText="Inventory"
                                            ItemStyle-CssClass="" />
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="50px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" Visible="true"
                                            ItemStyle-CssClass="" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind :

```
protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProduct.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Text.Equals(txt_AId1.Text)) //txt_AId1.Text is retrieved during pageload from url string
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works. The fact that it quickly disappears is an indication of another PostBack happening perhaps? Or a JavaScript snippet that is run.

Comment: @VDWWD I am also using JavaScript to filter my Gridview, is it because of which? If so how do I solve this?

Comment: That's probably it. But I cant solve it unless you post the relevant code. Check your javascript for css or color changes.